# Parse JSON Array With C#

Tags: c#, json

I am querying an API and returning data to a C# Console App.  I am able to query my data successfully except for the array element of such.  This is how the data is returned in JSON format

```
[
  {
    "UserType": "Admin",
    "UserPerms:" [
        {
            "level1:" "Yes",
            "level2:" "No", 
            "level3:" "No",
            "level4:" "Yes",
            "level5:" [
              {
                "door1:" "Yes",
                "door2:" "No", 
                "door3:" "No",
                "doory4:" "Yes"
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }         
]
```

And this is the C# syntax that I am trying to use to return the data - what is the proper C# syntax to return each door value for level5?

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string UserType { get; set; }
    public List<UserPerms> UserPerms { get; set; }
}
public class UserPerms
{
    public string level1 { get; set; }
    public string level2 { get; set; }
    public string level3 { get; set; }
    public string level4 { get; set; }
    public string[] level5 { get; set; }
}

public class Main[]
{
    var response = syncClient.DownloadString(url);
    var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(response);
    foreach (RootObject ro in o)
        if (ro.UserPerms != null)
            foreach (UserPerms info in ro.UserPerms)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Access to Level1" + info.level1);
                Console.WriteLine("Access to Level2" + info.level2);
                Console.WriteLine("Access to Level3" + info.level3);
                Console.WriteLine("Access to Level4" + info.level4);
                Console.WriteLine("Access to Level5" + info.level5);
            }
}
```

Comment: What is the intent of the pattern where you make everything an array with one object in it?

Comment: @EdPlunkett - for level5?  Or the overall syntax?  If the overall syntax - this was inherited from someone and the syntax works so I went with it...

Comment: It's a strange structure that appears to unnecessarily complicate things.

Comment: @Amy - how would you recommend the structure be set?

Comment: Why don't you follow the pattern as complicated as it looks/becomes? A new class for `level5` like `UserPerms` and then declare a `List<Level5>` in `UserPerms`.

Comment: Declare the List<level5> in UserPerms or in the RootObject?

Comment: @user2676140 In `UserPerms`, as appears in JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON for level5 displays a "list" of "key-value pair", so....

```
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> level5 { get; set; }
```

I'll try to come up with a fiddle soon.

Comment: how would I then write the results to the Console?

Comment: info.level5.door...
info.level5.door2... and so on

Comment: that gives an error of 'List<Dictionary<string,string>>' does not contain a definition for 'door1' and no extension method of 'door1' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Dictionary<string,string>>'  When I try to use Console.WriteLine("Access to Level5" + info.level5.door1);

Comment: You are declaring the array string in your main method - how would I declare it since the results are beingn returned from an API?

Comment: replace the line with "var json....." with  "var response = syncClient.DownloadString(url);"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146450/discussion-between-milan-and-user2676140).